# Idling motor and running AC for 4-8 hours in 100 degree heat?

Tags: ac, overheating, idle

Ok so I go to a lot of music festivals in the summer, stay up all night, then try to sleep during the day. A buddy swears by just idling his van engine and blasting the AC, like for 4-8 hours when it gets up to 100 degrees outside… I get that this will put significant wear on the engine, but so will driving it 500 miles, what I’m asking is will it be dangerous for it and cause expensive repairs? Can a modern engine take this without breaking down or causing serious problems, as long as I change the oil afterwards or something?

(I get that a generator would be better, but a lot of times festivals don’t allow them, or I’m traveling and am renting a van)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A generator would be criminally insane, that's how you die (or kill others) with carbon monoxide poisoning.  A modern car is less bad because it has pretty good emission controls.

Comment: In the dim past, when AC's in cars were add-ons (and anti-freeze was often just water, or a more dilute form of modern anti-freeze), often the engines were not up to the challenge of also running that AC, and would over-heat. And the more you wanted the AC, due to a hot day, the bigger the risk. But for several decades the engines have been designed anticipating AC loads, _and_ engine-cooling set-ups are better. So, you're certainly better off than 60 years ago. :)

Comment: Anecdotally - I once drove mid-Summer, middle of the day, from Orange County to Las Vegas in a soft-top Mustang with the roof down & the aircon on full tilt - contra to all the warning signs on the roadside all the way there. Did the same again 4 days later on the return journey. In my defence… it was a rental ;) It suffered no discernible ill at all.

Answer (score 7):

It shouldn't cause the vehicle any issues. Realistically, all you'll be doing is burning fuel. The wear will absolutely be minimal, mainly because at an idle, there is very little stress put onto the engine. Stress is what makes wear. The only thing I might be worried about is overheating the van. As long as the fans are running, this shouldn't be an issue, either.

There is a safety caveat to the occupants of the vehicle. You need to ensure the exhaust is in good shape and is routing the fumes correctly. Plus, you'll want to be in an open area. Even a parking garage could allow the exhaust fumes to be recirculated back into the cabin.

As an anecdote, we rented a passenger van one summer to go to a graduation down in Georgia. This was the year of the doretcho. We sat outside running the van in 100+ °F weather for hours waiting for things to happen. As far as I could tell, there was absolutely zero problems with the van for me doing this. It drove back to Virginia without issue. It didn't overheat during the period it was sitting still. It was a real troop, I have to say.

Comment: When you say the "doretcho", I'm guessing you mean "the" derecho... a derecho being the term for a strong progressive line of storms, tending to cause a lot of wind damage?  Perhaps the [2012 one in the eastern US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/June_2012_North_American_derecho)?  (Though there have been other notable ones in recent years, including the [2020 Iowa/Illinois one](https://www.washingtonpost.com/weather/2020/10/17/iowa-derecho-damage-cost/)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - it appears I have misspelled it, but you are correct. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: I wouldn't say that at all.  I would read the vehicle's manual.  The effect would be shortening the engine's service life, so you can't expect to see the damage by the time you return the car rental or return a lease or sell a car every 3-4 years if that's how you roll. As far as exhaust you need to make sure it's a post-2000 car and that it passes smog. (these computers are so reliable that California doesn't bother with sniffer smog tests on post-2000 cars, yes I know 2000 != 1996, I didn't write the law.)